# Getting error EXC_BAD_ACCESS during fetching data from custome objects

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I had 10 custome objects which are stored in array. here is my code. facebook_wallDataArray is NSMUtable array.

```
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
   FacebookWallData* wallPost=[[FacebookWallData alloc]init];
    wallPost.messages=@"Wall Values";
[facebook_wallDataArray addObject:wallPost];

            [wallPost release];
}
```

Now I have a function which is storing object values in TableView Array. I am calling     function like here.

```
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
 [self faceboookDisplay:i]
}
```

And here is my function body.

```
-(void) facebookDisplayFunction:(int)atIndex {

     FacebookWallData* wall=[[FacebookWallData alloc]init];

    wall=[facebook_wallDataArray objectAtIndex:atIndex];

       [tableList addObject:wall.messages];
     [wall release];
 }
```

But my program is being crashed with an exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I am not getting where is my code wrong? facebook_wallDataArray has storing values like this.It is NSMUtableArray.

```
"<FacebookWallData: 0x4c52ee0>",
"<FacebookWallData: 0x4c52df0>",
"<FacebookWallData: 0x6828300>",
"<FacebookWallData: 0x6826d50>",
"<FacebookWallData: 0x4e25a10>",
"<FacebookWallData: 0x9317c60>",
"<FacebookWallData: 0x4c53190>",
"<FacebookWallData: 0x4e47e90>",
"<FacebookWallData: 0x4c53380>",
"<FacebookWallData: 0x93176e0>",
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You create a new walldata object, but then you get the one from the array. So you lose the pointer to the one you just created ( memory leak ) and release an **autoreleased** object from an NSArray => crash

Do this instead:

```
-(void) facebookDisplayFunction:(int)atIndex 
{
     FacebookWallData* wall = nil;
     wall = [facebook_wallDataArray objectAtIndex:atIndex];
     [tableList addObject:wall.messages];
}
```

**E:** Another thing, you are statically looping 10 times, I think it would be better if you'd use the count of the array instead, if the size of the array changes but you forgot to change the number in the for loop then you will get an exception, which will break your app.

Comment: I changed the code but now I am getting EXC-BAD_ACCESS in loop where function is being called. In this line " [self facebookDisplayFunction:i]; ". I changed also static number to array count.

Comment: whenevr I want to call function again and again it is throwing excepttion.

Comment: Then you are overreleasing something again, the only place where you need to release something manually is in the first loop, not the ones after it